# Unhandled Exception handling in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

```
[STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.ThreadException +=
                new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
            Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
            Application.Run(new Form1());                
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {                

        }
    }
static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
   //Code
}
static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
   //Code
}
```

In Form1.cs I have the following.

```
private void backgroundWorkerLogin_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     throw new Exception("Test");
}
```

Still the exception is shown as unhandled. Can anyone suggest how to catch the exception by the event handler declared above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ThreadException` event is only for the UI thread. All exceptions that occurs in other threads are not caught.

You can use `AppDomain.Current.UnhandledException` event to catch those. You can however not prevent the application from crashing using that event.

You therefore always have to make sure to use `try`/`catch` in all other threads.

Comment: I am using the AppDomain.Current.UnhandledException, still it doesn't work. Am I doing it wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `Still the exception is shown as unhandled`. Your `UnhandledException` event can't prevent your application from crashing.